# How to show password view page before actual view page in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, redirect, django-views, django-templates

I created a diary web app in Django. It stores all diaries encrypted. I want to ask password when a user tries to view or update or delete his/her diary. It doesn't mean a login is required. I want to ask user's password even though the user login. I tried to create a decorator for this but I couldn't complete it. I have two views:

This view check to password is correct:

```py
def check_master_password_view(request):
    page = 'check'
    profile = request.user.profile
    if request.method == "POST":
        checked = check_master_password(request.POST['password'], profile.master_password)
        if checked:
            return checked # OR Redirect another page
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'You entered wrong password !')
    context = {
        'page':page,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/create_or_check_master_password.html', context)
```

Another view is detail view:

```py
def detail_diary_view(request, pk):
    profile = request.user.profile
    diary = profile.diary_set.get(id=pk)
    diary.diary = decrypt_diary(request, diary.diary)
    context = {
        'diary': diary
    }
    return render(request, 'diary/detail_diary.html', context)
```

When the user clicks the link to view the diary, I want to show check_master_password view. If the user enters the correct password I want to redirect to the actual page (view, update, delete pages). How can I do this?

Comment: Is first in question function `decorator` ?

Comment: Actually, it was a view function. I tried to create a decorator but I couldn't find any solution.